# adding elements to the button when the div.el-pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the code the JavaScript code which is what i am trying to add the `aria-label` but somewhat it is missing somewhere

```
document.querySelectorAll('.el-pagination').forEach(button => button.setAttribute('aria-label',(button.getElementsByClassName('el-icon-arrow-left').length == 1) ? 'Previous' : 'Next'));
```

This is my code for the html

```
<div class="el-pagination" aria-label="Previous">
  <span class="el-pagination__sizes">
    <div class="el-select el-select--mini">
      <!---->
      <div class="el-input el-input--mini el-input--suffix">
        <!---->
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select" class="el-input__inner">
        <!---->
        <span class="el-input__suffix">
          <span class="el-input__suffix-inner">
            <i class="el-select__caret el-input__icon el-icon-arrow-up"></i>
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
          </span>
          <!---->
        </span>
        <!---->
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div class="el-select-dropdown el-popper pagination-popper" style="display: none; min-width: 175px;">
        <div class="el-scrollbar" style="">
          <div class="el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;">
            <ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list">
              <!---->
              <li class="el-select-dropdown__item selected">
                <span>50 items per page</span>
              </li>
              <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
                <span>100 items per page</span>
              </li>
              <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
                <span>150 items per page</span>
              </li>
              <li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
                <span>300 items per page</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-horizontal">
            <div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-vertical">
            <div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateY(0%);"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
  <button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn-prev">
    <i class="el-icon el-icon-arrow-left"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="el-pager">
    <li class="number active">1</li>
    <!---->
    <li class="number">2</li>
    <li class="number">3</li>
    <li class="number">4</li>
    <!---->
    <li class="number">5</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" class="btn-next">
    <i class="el-icon el-icon-arrow-right"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

so something in my `JavaScript` is going wrong which i can't figure what is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add aria-label to the elements in html without using any js here

But if you want you can also do it using js like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-prev').forEach(button => button.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Previous'))
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-next').forEach(button => button.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Next'))
```